# How to determine which thread implementation binary compiled with

Tags: linux, elf, libraries

Is it possible to determine if a binary  (static or shared and not stripped) is compiled with Linuxthreads or NPTL implementation ?

Comment: Sorry for the half published message ... I don't know what happened but the rest of it was cut and I noticed it later ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but I'll cite two. Usually, a binary file, if not stripped,  contains symbols (function names, variable names, ...). These symbols are usually used to ease debugging and are stored using a certain format, DWARF for example.

The first method is to disassemble the binary and look for specific threading libraries related symbols. For example :

```
    objdump -D ./YOUR_PROGRAM | grep -i thread
```

The second one is to hijack the threading library function calls using your own library and **LD_PRELOAD**. The concept is fairly simple, you write a library (.so) in which you implement the functions which you want to check for, let's say **pthread_create** or **pthread_join**, and reimplement it this way :

```
    int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, 
                       const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                       void *(*start_routine) (void *), 
                       void *arg)
    {
          int ret;
          static void *(*ext_pthread_create)(pthread *, 
                                             const pthread_attr_t *,
                                             void *,
                                             void *);

          ext_pthread_create = dlsym("RTLD_NEXT", pthread_create);
          ret = ext_pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);

          printf("pthread_create called !\n");

          return ret;
     }
```

All you have to do after compiling and testing your library is call yor program this way :

```
    LD_PRELOAD=hooklib.so ./YOUR_PROGRAM PARAMS
```

If the function is called, you'll see the printf message on the standard output.

Comment: If I cannot execute the binary since it is different architecture objdump -D ./YOUR_PROGRAM | grep -i thread  is the only way ? What can I expect as output depending on implementation used ?

Comment: Yes, the `objdump` way will work ... but it's not very classy though. One, it necessitates a non stripped binary, and two you need to check for all threading library symbols (Pthread, OpenMP, Boost, ...). I believe the hook mechanism is much classier, but of course it requires a lot more code and the ability to run he binary (which can be done either by using a virtual machine, an emulator, ...). Honestly, most of the ways I have in mind need the binary to be run. The only static approach I can think of now is the `grep` one.

Comment: So what strings to look for to find out implementation? I tried one unstripped file and got lots of things with pthread which does not indicate neccesarily anything ?

Comment: Well, you should look for function names that create threads : `pthread_create` & `pthread_join` if it's the Pthread library. If `grep` finds something, well, you hit the jackpot. If grep outputs nothing, then there's no Pthreads calls.
Note : you should research the other threading libraries in case & also test the `clone()` syscall.

Comment: You might have misunderstood my question maybe. I was not asking to determine if software is written with threading . But determine which thread implementation. Linuxthreads or NPTL which are similar but different things.

Comment: No, I understood your question ... This is why I added the "Note". In your case all you'll have to do is grep the symbols/function names from those two libraries.